# Como acessar o conteúdo de uma requisão curl com php?

Tags: php, libcurl, facebook

Eu estou desenvolvendo um bot em php que pega as postagens do feed de uma pagina do facebook usando curl via requisição GET. Eu quero extrair certas informações da pagina para depois colocar em contentes e exibir em um site bom essa parte eu desenrolo, mas eu não sei se a função curl retorna um array ou uma string me parece ser uma string minha duvida é o curl tem alguma função para acessar os dados por ela retornado ou tem que fazer um parse no conteudo?
o codigo da requisição do bot:

```
<?php
    define("VERSAO", "/v2.10", TRUE);
    define("PAGINA", "/resultadojogodobicho", TRUE);
    define("GRAPH", "?fields=feed{full_picture,message}", TRUE);
    define("ACCESS_TOKEN", "&access_token=...", TRUE); 
    define("URL", "https://graph.facebook.com", TRUE);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, URL.VERSAO.PAGINA.GRAPH.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    if($return){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, essa API retorna um JSON e por padrão o parâmetro *CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER* do *curl_setopt* faz o *curl_exec* retornar uma string mesmo em caso de sucesso, conforme documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php.
Sendo assim, só tu decodificar o string do JSON retornado e se quiser que se torne um array, setar o segundo parâmetro da função como **true**. O script ficaria assim no seu caso:

```
$return = curl_exec($ch);
if($return){
    $json_decoded = json_decode($return, true);
}else{
    echo 0;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: mano ela retorna um json mesmo eu dei um var_dump e me retornou um json era isso mesmo valeu @Marcelo Bicudo